# How to create an Action Overflow like drop down list for any MenuItem in a contexual action bar

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, android-actionbar

I would like to create drop down lists on several menu items in a contexual action bar or action mode like what is shown with the Action Overflow menu item. I assume it is possible since the Action Overflow MenuItem does use one but can someone point me in the right direction to allow other MenuItems to use one?

Comment: "I would like to create drop down lists on several menu items in a contexual action bar or action mode like what is shown with the Action Overflow menu item." -- I have tried and tried and have never gotten this to work. You can define it, the same way as you would for the regular action bar, but the user cannot click it.

Comment: @CommonsWare Hmmm... just the confirmation I was looking for, thank you. I will have to customise a ListView to create a solution to this problem I reckon

Comment: Actually, reviewing [the issue I filed related to this](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=23381), my problems might have been limited to `EditText`. Again, to set up the overflow on an action mode, use the same approach as you would for the regular action bar (e.g., `android:showAsAction="never"`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found out how to do this if I may answer my own question for people having this same problem. I found out you can use a [PopupMenu](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#PopupMenu) or [PopupWindow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html) and set it to display as a Dropdown Menu in the bottom left corner of the anchor view. You can also move it around to make it seem as if it came from an item pressed in a contexual Actionbar

Comment: Congrats on the fix!  Remember, it's fine to [ask and answer your own question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/).  When you are able, please make sure to mark your answer as 'accepted' so that others will be able to learn from your success.  Cheers~